# Why need I add self when assign attibute for one model?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I have one model.

I want to update one attribute each 3 seconds after init, and I need to change the attribute in one other view controller later.

the code is:

### MODEL

```
 @interface Ap : NSObject        
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sessionId;

    + (id)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation Ap
    @synthesize  sessionId, address;
    -(id) init {
        if (self = [super init])  {
            self.address = nil;
            self.sessionId = nil;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(heartbeat) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) updateSession{
       sessionId = @"some string";
    }

    - (void) update{
       self.sessionId = @"some value from network";
    }


    + (Ap *)sharedInstance {
      if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
       }
       return sharedInstance;
    }
@end
```

### CONTROLLER

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[Ap sharedInstance] updateSession];
}
```

---

The error is: `(lldb) bad access` when model update

And I change the updateSession method to

```
     -(void) updateSession{
        self.sessionId = @"some string";
     }
```

The error is gone, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: please add the timer implemention + the definition of the Ap property

Comment: @Daij-Djan  `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sessionId;
`

Comment: @Daij-Djan `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(heartbeat) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; `

Comment: You may want try to find out your app crashed in which line.

Open the breakpoint navigation in XCode 4 (This looks like a rectangle with a point on the right side)
Press the '+' button at the bottom left and add an 'Exception Breakpoint'. Ensure you break 'On Throw' for 'All' exceptions.

Then you can get a stack call back and point out what's wrong. If you can not handle it, post the line in which the app crashes and let's see what happened

Comment: @why, Did you check with my code? Did it work or are you still facing the same crash?

Comment: Sorry, it can not work. By the way I define Ap model in delegate is `@property(nonatomic, retain) Ap *ap;
`

Comment: @why, Why? If it is declared as `@property` you should use `self.ap` and not just `ap` to reference the variable. Otherwise it will crash. That is the reason why we normally declare it as `@property` so that we can use it as `self.ap`.

Comment: I think if you are still facing issue, you should post the crash message after trying my code. You should get a proper message now since the retain issue will be resolved. We should be able to help based on the crash message.

Comment: I update the debug info :p

Comment: I think you are right , the getAp method can not load the correct Ap model

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21673/discussion-between-acb-and-why)

Comment: Did you try with my code? and then you got this crash? Can you paste the console message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `self.ap = [[Ap alloc] init];` in your app delegate. Your model object might be getting released when you try to call `update` on that which might cause a crash.

Your code will look like this,

```
@interface SomeAppDelegate : UIResponder{
@property(nonatomic, retain) Ap *ap; //declare property here
@end 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(!self.ap){ 
        self.ap = [[Ap alloc] init]; //use property here as self.ap which will retain ap. Otherwise it will not retain it.
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Looks like you have removed the previous question and added a completely new question to the previous one. Anyways I will try to answer this one as well.

> The error is gone, can anyone tell me why?

The reason is same as what I mentioned above. If you use `self.sessionId = @"some string";`, you are retaining the object. Because it is a property and a property will internally retain since you have declared that property as retain. But if you use `sessionId = @"some string";`,  its scope is only inside that method since you are not using the property. You are directly setting the value without calling property and it will autoreleased after that method. And hence you will get a `bad access`.

I would suggest you to go through the apple documentation to understand more about properties and its working.

Comment: Can you try this code, and then let me know what is the crash now after this?

Comment: @why, Updated my answer. It is the same issue as before. You didnt use property by calling self.sessionId and it will crash. I think I had already mentioned it above in `self.ap` where you did the same mistake.